# Typescript two generics that are compatible in function

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I have a function that accepts two callbacks with single arguments, like this:

`function f<T1, T2>(a: (input: T1) => number, b: (input: T2) => number) {}`

What is want is that T1 and T2 should have such a relation that T1 is assignable to T2. That is, I want it to accept such call:

`f((input: {a: number, b: number}) => 2, (input: {a: number}) => 4);`

as {a: number, b: number} is assignable to {a: number}. But such call should not compile:

`f((input: {}) => 2, (input: {a: number}) => 4);`

What I tried doing is rewriting my function declaration in the following way:

`function f<T1 extends T2, T2>(a: (input: T1) => number, b: (input: T2) => number) {}`

But somehow the second example still gets compiled. Somehow, Typescripts assigns type {a: number} to T1 as well.....

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZa51N) work for your use case?  If so, I'll write up an answer explaining what's going on.  If not, please explain what's not working about it so I can address it.

Comment: @jcalz it does! Thank you! An explanation would be great as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason you're running into trouble is that function types are *contravariant* in the types of their parameters (see [Difference between Variance, Covaraince, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more details).  For example:

```
const contravariantFuncParam: (a: { x: string, y: number }) => void =
    (a: { x: string }) => { }; // okay
// {x: string} is assignable to {x: string, y: number}

const notCovariantFuncParam: (a: { x: string }) => void =
    (a: { x: string, y: number }) => { }; // error! 
// {x: string, y: number} is not assignable to {x: string}
```

So for the following definition,

```
function f<T1 extends T2, T2>(a: (input: T1) => number, b: (input: T2) => number) { }
```

the compiler happily accepts this:

```
f((input: {}) => 2, (input: { a: number }) => 4);
```

Roughly, the type `T2` is inferred from the input to the `b` callback as `{a: number}`.  Then the compiler knows that `T1` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `{a: number}`.  Since function types are contravariant in their parameters, the compiler sees that `(input: {}) => number` is assignable to `(input: {a: number}) => number`, and thus the `a` input is accepted.  And `T1` falls back to the constraint `{a: number}`.

You'd prefer `T2` and `T1` to be inferred from `b` and `a` directly, and then only later enforce `T1 extends T2`.  But by having `T1` constrained to `T2` this doesn't happen.

---

One way to do this is to move the `T1 extends T2` clause out of the constraint position, and instead use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) for the input to `a`:

```
function f<T1, T2>(
  a: (input: T1 extends T2 ? T1 : unknown) => number, 
  b: (input: T2) => number
) { }

f((input: { a: number, b: number }) => 2, (input: { a: number }) => 4); // okay
f((input: {}) => 2, (input: { a: number }) => 4); // error
```

This works because when faced with inferring from a conditional type like `A extends B ? C : D`, the compiler will plug in its inferred type for `A` and then evaluate it.  So `T1 extends T2 ? T1 : unknown` will cause the compiler to infer `T1` as the input type to the passed-in `a` callback.  If `T1 extends T2` is true, then this is a no-op and the type for `input` evaluates to `T1`.  Otherwise, the type for `input` will evaluate to `unknown`... which, by contravariance of function parameters, will almost certainly fail to accept whatever was passed in.

---

At this point I see that the two type parameters aren't really necessary, at least for this example.  If you could *infer* `T1` from `a` and not from `b`, then later go back and just *check* that `T1` is usable as `b`'s callback parameter type (which you used to call `T2`).  If so, then `(input: T2)=> number` is assignable to `(input: T`) => number`, and thus (by contravariance of function arguments) that` T1 extends T2`. So let's get rid of` T2`and just use`T`instead of`T1`.

The tricky part here is how to tell the compiler that you want `T` to be inferred from `a` and not inferred from `b`.  For `b`'s `input` type, you want a `NoInfer<T>` where `NoInfer` means "just check this, don't use it to infer".  If we had such a thing, you could write `f()` like this:

```
function f<T>(a: (input: T) => number, b: (input: NoInfer<T>) => number) { }
```

There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) for a way to mark *non-inferential type parameter usage*.  No *official* solutions exist, but there are a few suggestions that work for some use cases, like `type NoInfer<T> = T & {}` from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731).  I tend to use [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546):

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

Using this definition leads to your desired behavior:

```
f((input: { a: number, b: number }) => 2, (input: { a: number }) => 4); // okay
f((input: {}) => 2, (input: { a: number }) => 4); // error
```

---

Both of the above solutions are using tricks/workarounds to try to alter the compiler's type inference behavior.  And these tricks are not guaranteed to work in all possible circumstances.  Conditional type inference and `NoInfer` implementations have their pitfalls.  So for either solution I strongly recommend extensive testing against likely use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgkikAzAV2HgBcMB7YUgHgBUBGJCADyomABMoSZgCYANEOEA+ABQgAXEmkZgMMlQVsAlEgC8kpMDJgARhDTjjCpSrUbh2vQaOm023EgC+hYiWnXV6ngeDvpiisoBCu7yTiZmniFIACyaANz4XvhZ8PRQVEg5wFRoIABuIJggRQBiFPAAChXgVjHunAp5mMBY4gCeCoZxaAm6+qW0GHy63kSyUUjtSJ3KOMGjeJ6pSAD020i0ANYgvfi7eIvL3R5IGIIgUFDYoMYANshUtOcdxSt9A85mTKFPIGWhUADCtHKlRqdUaJTALXmFx+3RGjnGk2mxEUrQW3y6PSQ-ViLnR+ncHi2ZzMaFoaAAhEhTntcCjCX9SYCboJgGCkPdHlhnm8kB8vktUVhMvhQJBYAhkMwAO6fAg48iUGj0JhscQiGQxfy2ITsLg8fiCERIAD8pqQCgoBz5yuAiUGLgsVgiJpE7oBrg2Xg1fh9gWi-yGXq5wzWjjCxvDAsjZLj+hS1L2h2OM1IoZs4bTSATYfmMQ98SLGZ2e1p9IyWVl4GgcEQQgAFmgIMh1cQqL0YMgAHK0ACSwBIZhY+h0SAA2swALoLjjcXgCAXAXq2pAABgdBggpTMi-SGrq2oYJGnc3CBY0-qjSEsd8iSBH48naGnj5cbk8ua+ImZYpmY0YVrGiQlveGzlgG5LJGkNb7EcJwhsBQRQeIGERjGCHVjSaB0mgDb4EAA)